# Does a charge difference necessitate a potential difference?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy, voltage

> Consider two metal objects, X and Y that when connected by a conducting wire results in a transfer of electrons from Y to X. What can be concluded about X and Y before the connection was made:
>
> A) X had greater electric charge compared to Y
>
> B) X had great electric potential compared to Y

Now obviously, if there is a potential difference, there will exist an electric field that can result in a movement of charge — and this is the answer provided.

However, if X has a greater electric charge when they are connected doesn't this also intuitively mean there will be movement of electrons as they try balance the difference? Furthermore, going by the definition of voltage as the work done in moving a unit charge from one sphere to the isn't there also a voltage difference?

So why isn't A also a valid answer?

Comment: Note that the question specifies that there is a transfer of *electrons* from Y to X, and that electrons are negatively charged. In what direction would electrons be forced if X had a greater potential than Y? How do charges (negative charges in particular) respond to differences in potential?

Comment: @D.W. My bad, the question was about about why **A** isn't also a valid answer. I understand why B is true, not sure about why A isn't always necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a sphere of radius $R$ with charge $+Q$ on it.
The potential of sphere $X$ is $+\frac{kQ}{R}$.

Let $Y$ be another sphere of radius $6R$ with charge $+5Q$ on it.
The potential of sphere $Y$ is $+\frac{k5Q}{6R}$.

The potential of sphere $X$ is larger than that of sphere $Y$ so if the spheres are connected with a wire electrons will flow from sphere $Y$ to sphere $X$.  This is the correct answer.

Note that in this case the charge on sphere $Y$ is greater than the charge on sphere $X$ which contradicts the other possible answer.